# How to access MaterialIconsFont.ttf from core project using dll/nuget in Xamarin forms (MAUI)?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, maui, .net-maui

I have created two .Net MAUI projects. One is core project and other one is child project. I want to create nuget package for all the common features like Style, Fonts and controls etc.

For this I have added MaterialFontIcons.ttf file in Core project and I have also created a Static FontIconHelper class to access all the fonts available in ttf file.

I want to use this same icons in my child project so I have used core project's dll file into the Child project. I was able to access the FontIconHelper class but I'm not able to access the ttf file it self.

I have to add the MaterialFontIcons.ttf file in my Chile project as well than only Icon shows when I run the app otherwise it shows "?" icon.

Here is what I have done:

#### Core Project Steps:

1 Downloaded Material design font file from https://materialdesignicons.com/

2 Added MaterialFontIcons.ttf in Resources --> Fonts folder.

3 Set it's build action to MauiFont.

4 Registered font in Dependency injection to use it in child project.

5 Created static FontIconHelper.cs class to access ttf icons/fonts.

5 I have build the solution and got the .dll file from it's /bin folder

##### FontIconHelper.cs class

```
public static class FontIconHelper
{
    public const string MaterialDesignIconsFont = "MaterialDesignIconsFont";

    public const string VectorSquare = "\U000f0001";
    public const string AccessPointNetwork = "\U000f0002";
    public const string AccessPoint = "\U000f0003";
    public const string Account = "\U000f0004";
}
```

#### Child Project Steps:

1 I have added dll file generated from Master project here.
2 Tried to access FontIcon in Xaml like this:

```
Added name space: xmlns:helper="clr-namespace:Mobile.UI.Core.Helpers;assembly=Mobile.UI.Core"

<Image x:Name="image" HeightRequest="20" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
    <Image.Source>
        <FontImageSource
            Glyph="{x:Static helper:FontIconHelper.AccessPoint}"
            Size="20"
            Color="Black"
            FontFamily="{x:Static helper:FontIconHelper.MaterialDesignIconsFont}"/>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

3 When run the app it shows square with "?" instead of actual icon.

4 Then I have added ttf file in Chile project and set it's build action to MauiFont and registered the font in MauiProgram.cs like this:

```
var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
builder
    .UseMauiApp<App>()
    .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
    {
        fonts.AddFont("MaterialdesignIcons-Font.ttf", "MaterialdesignIconsFont");
    })
    .ConfigureServices();
```

After this it shows icon property in App.

Does anyone know how to access Fonts.ttf file directly from the Core project to Child project without adding it to the Child project?

Comment: For what it is worth, the current architectural recommendation is to avoid using font icons and instead only include the individual SVG icon files that your app needs. This reduces app bloat as the Material Design icon set is now over 7k icons and growing by 100 every release. No app needs that many icons. You can search for and download SVG versions of the icons from here: https://pictogrammers.com/library/mdi/

Answer (score 2):

you need to assign ttf as embedded resource in csproj for passing between class libraries. Alternatively you can use icon libraries that already does the job.

Here's one some icon library that based on material icon.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/AathifMahir.Maui.MauiIcons.Material

Also you can look for other variants as well here.
https://www.nuget.org/profiles/Aathif_Mahir

Answer (score 1):

First you must create your own **MauiAppBuilder** in some place of the Core project. Can be a class like this:

```
  public static class AppBuilderExtensions
  {    
    public static MauiAppBuilder UseRamdomFunctionNameXYZASDF( this MauiAppBuilder builder )
    {      
            builder = FontsMauiAppBuilderExtensions.ConfigureFonts(builder, (Action<IFontCollection>)(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("MaterialdesignIcons-Font.ttf", "MaterialdesignIconsFont");
            }));
            return builder;
        }   
  }
```

Then in your MauiProgram.cs set:

```
var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
builder
    .UseMauiApp<App>()
    .UseRamdomFunctionNameXYZASDF()//this is it, also you can use for add styles and similar
    .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
    {
        //here you inserted here the Material fonts before... no needed anymore
    })
    .ConfigureServices();
```

I tested this and works for me... also the fonts (.ttf) can be in any folder of the Core project and works.
Hope helps you

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a new file "AssemblyInfo.cs" to the core projects root folder with:

```
[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)] 
[assembly: ExportFont("MaterialdesignIcons-Font.ttf", Alias = "MaterialdesignIconsFont")]
```